# cpanel won't delete add on domain. error "You do not have control of the subdomain for"

Tags: cpanel, subdomain, whm

***My employer is strictly against SSH changes, so please try to find another way of solving this. He had a previous employee who broke something on cpanel when trying to fix an issue with SSH, which is why there is no convincing him.***

There is an add-on domain on a server we work with, it is linked to a subdomain. When I go to cpanel and try to delete the subdomain - it says I must delete the add on domain first. When I try to delete the add-on domain it gives me the following error: "You do not have control of the subdomain for {x}.com". I try to unpark the subdomain in WHM and it says "Unable to find out which user owns the parked domain {x}.com" . How do I go about to fix this using cpanel/ whm?

Comment: I researched this on google and every solution I have found did not work.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, remove it manually as explained here http://crybit.com/how-to-remove-parked-domain-command-line-cpanel/ , the first 2 steps are wrong as you should look for the domain on the users file like 'grep domain.com /var/cpanel/users/user' and remove the lines that reference the domain, also you should edit the file /var/cpanel/userdata/user/main and remove the domain there as well as the file /var/cpanel/userdata/user/domain.com .

To remove it from the dns just do /scripts/killdns domain.com

The rest in the article should be good enough. Never modify apache config file directly, better to modify the cpanel files and then run /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf and verify your changes did work.

Hope this helps.